# 2K versus Quad HD (QHD)

Tags: film-techniques

Is there a REAL difference or is it both the same.

According to a German Wikipedia article 2K is a resolution with a width of UP TO 2048 pixels. Therefore 2560x1440 doesn't fit into this range. Furthermore on the [English 2K article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2K_resolution) I can see only resolutions less or equal than 2048, so it somehow seems to confirm the German article.

However I can find a lot of articles saying 2K and QHD are all the same, e.g. on [this page](http://www.androidpit.com/full-hd-vs-quad-hd-vs-4k-phone-screen-resolutions).

Some other sources say, that 2K indicates all resolutions with a width of 2000 pixels or more. To be certain, I would like to know, whats right and whats wrong.

Is QHD a part of 2K or is it not? Or is it the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[QHD is 4 times 720p](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/QHD-quad-high-definition), thus a width of 2560 pixels. It will only be a QHD display if it reaches this resolution.
2K, however, is supposed to have somewhere around 2000 pixels (the K stands for kilo meaning "times 1000"). The 2K, 4K and 8K terms are more generic than QHD, UHD (3840 pixels × 2160) and FUHD (7680 × 4320).

So QHD has an exact definition of the resolution, while 2K doesn't, still QHD is in the range of 2,000 pixels (it certainly is not 4K).
Manufacters of hardware use both terms interchangebly to sell their hardware.
For example [LG](http://www.stuff.tv/g3/lg-confirms-g3-will-have-2k-qhd-screen/news) and [Samsung](http://www.androidheadlines.com/2014/01/samsung-confirms-qhd-2k-uhd-4k-amoled-displays-works.html) do.

So QHD is part of 2K, but it is not the same (a 2048p resolution is 2K, but not QHD).

Comment: 2K is not a loosely coined term pulled in by the hairs by some people. No, 2K originates from the DCI-standard that was the ~17:9- cinema display equivalent (2048x1080) of the 16:9 monitor resolution FullHD (1920x1080). So no, 2K isn't anything in the two thousand range of horizontal pixels, it's exactly 2048x1080 and thus should never be used for any other resolution.

Comment: If you refer to the DCI definition of 2K then yes you are right. However, hardware manifacters also throw around the term "2K" on devices that do not have exactly 2048x1080 pixels

Comment: When they do, we shouldn't just accept that. We must reject that unruly behaviour and let them stick to clear names and monikers. Anyway, unlike the 4k moniker, I haven't seen manufacturers and marketeers use the term 2k to be honest. Only silly people on the internet decided to use that to mean QHD, but it's clearly a very fuzzy name for that resolution. People should know they cannot make up names for things; better use the ones that already exist, damn it!

Comment: I agree with you, but it's all about marketing, new flashy abbreviations sell. Also this monitor is marketed as having 2K resolution, while the resolution is higher than 2048x1080:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824025424